# UWP - Display Progress Bar in ItemTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building a UWP app for Windows Mobile but I've hit a bit of a snag with progress bars. I got one working on the first page on app launch, that's fine, but now I'm trying to show one inside a GridView. I will have N number of GridView controls on the screen at any one time, and want to display a ProgressBar in each.

This works fine with the data binding and data will show, but when I tried to add an indeterminate ProgressBar before the TextBlock it doesn't seem to show. I can only assume I'm either putting it in the wrong place or I'm doing it wrong as my GridView is using `GridView.ItemTemplate`.

Here are some screenshots:

[Without data in the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ft27.png)

[With data in the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dLvt.png)

## Update with Answer

With Justin XL's help I've managed to get to the bottom of the issue. I was binding to a normal clr property and not a DependencyProperty. I changed my code to use MVVM and setup the IsLoaded property to handle notifying the UI. Here is my updated and working code:

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> MyData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();

    private bool _isLoaded;

    public bool IsLoaded
    {
        get { return _isLoaded; }
        set
        {
            _isLoaded = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        // Add items to MyData
        IsLoaded = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel Vm => DataContext as MainPageViewModel;

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        await Vm.GetDataAsync();
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```cs
<Page
    x:Class="MultiGridProgressBars.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MultiGridProgressBars"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:MultiGridProgressBars.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <GridView IsHitTestVisible="{x:Bind Vm.IsLoaded, Mode=OneWay}"
            Header="A Grid View"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            x:Name="MyDataListView1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.MyData}"
            Width="164" 
            Margin="10,53,0,53">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ViewModel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
                            <Run Text="{ x:Bind Name }"></Run>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 10"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**App.xaml**

```cs
<Application
        x:Class="MultiGridProgressBars.App"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:MultiGridProgressBars"
        xmlns:converters="using:MultiGridProgressBars.Converters"
        RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <converters:InvertIsCheckedVisiblityConverter x:Key="InvertIsCheckedVisiblityConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="GridView">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,10" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                        <ContentThemeTransition />
                        <ReorderThemeTransition />
                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                        <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                            BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                            IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                            IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                            IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                            IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                            IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                            TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                            VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                            ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                <ItemsPresenter FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                                FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                                Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                                HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                                Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>

                            <ProgressBar x:Name="StatusBar"
                                             Visibility="{Binding IsHitTestVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InvertIsCheckedVisiblityConverter}}"
                                             IsIndeterminate="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**InvertIsCheckedVisiblityConverter.cs**

```cs
public class InvertIsCheckedVisiblityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool isChecked = (bool) value;
        return isChecked ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any sort of size for the `ProgressBar`. You should assign a non-zero `Height`, and at a minimum set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`, if not explicitly specify a `Width`. If you need more help than that, please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: The ProgressBar is a copy&paste from another page where it works fine, or is this a bit more specific to using it within a DataTemplate? I'll give it a go though.

Comment: It could be anything. Without seeing a [mcve] for each, that accurately represents both your source for the copy/paste and how you're using the pasted code, I can't say precisely why it works in one place and not the other. Maybe the original source had a style declared somewhere that applied dimensions to `ProgressBar`, for example. (By the way, I mis-typed in my comment above...I meant to recommend `Stretch` for `HorizontalAlignment`, not `Center`; only `Stretch` would automatically resize the element to fit the available width.)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The other ProgressBar is actually sitting outside of the GridView which is presumably why it's visible. I feel like the issue here is because I'm using ItemsSource on the GridView - If the ObservableCollection it's watching is empty, I'm assuming there'll be no items in the GridView! (and hence no ProgressBar as it's inside the Item template)

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure it's only the `ProgressBar` that's not showing?

Comment: _"I feel like the issue here is because I'm using ItemsSource on the GridView"_ -- yes and no. The basic scenario works fine. There's nothing inherent about putting the `ProgressBar` element in a template used inside some collection view. So, in that sense, no. But of course, the context is different and there's obviously something about that difference preventing the display. You can keep posting comments, or you can put a good [mcve] in your question. Your choice. The latter is the only thing likely to lead to a solution though.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the full `<GridView>` code and some screenshots of the results of both having no data and having data. All the code-behind is doing is making asynchronous Http calls and pushing the parse JSON into the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Now I don't understand what you want. I can clearly see the progress bar on your second screenshot.

Comment: Hi Justin. What I'm trying to achieve is *one* ProgressBar in the center of the entire GridView before any data has been pushed to the MyData collection. When the screen loads, display GridView with single ProgressBar -> Get Data -> Hide ProgressBar & show grid items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `ProgressBar` that sits in the center of the `GridView`, you need to wrap your `GridView` within a `Grid` and place the `ProgressBar` on top of your `GridView`. Something like this -

```
<Grid>
    <GridView />

    <ProgressBar x:Name="StatusBar"
                 IsIndeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>
</Grid>
```

Of course you only want to show it's progressing when the data is loading, so you will need a property like `IsLoading` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then bind `IsIndeterminate` to it.

```
IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsLoading}"
```

---

### Update

To make it simpler, you can also wrap the `ProgressBar` inside a `GridView` style. First just generate a new style based on the default one, and then go to its `ControlTemplate` and change the root panel from `Border` to `Grid`, and then just place a `ProgressBar` there, like this -

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
    <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                      BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                      HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                      IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                      IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                      IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                      TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                      VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                      ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
            <ItemsPresenter FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                            FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                            Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ProgressBar x:Name="StatusBar"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsHitTestVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You will also need a *bool* property to control the loading of the `ProgressBar`. Here we can just use an existing property `IsHitTestVisible`. Note you will also need to invert the value using a converter.

Finally, you can just directly manipulate the loading visual by doing this -

```
<GridView IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsLoaded}" Style="{StaticResource LoadingGridViewStyle}" />
```

Comment: I'll be using N number of GridViews on the screen though. I could have up to about 5 GridViews (scrolled horizontally) to display data and I want each one to have its own progressbar, tacking a different ObservableCollection. I think using this approach I'd need to have multiple `<Grid>`s as well for each GridView in view

Comment: Perhaps this image I knocked up in XD will help demonstrate what I'm after: http://i.imgur.com/oVHgxIw.png. (a little new to UWP and XAML)

Comment: Thank you for providing that, I'll give that a try later today and let you know.

Comment: I can't seem to get the progressbar showing (items still become visible, however). I have put the ControlTemplate inside my <GridView> element at the bottom, bound to IsHitTestVisible as suggested. On the GridView: `<GridView IsHitTestVisible="{ Binding IsLoaded }" Style="{StaticResource LoadingGridViewStyle}"` with `IsLoaded` being a public bool on the code-behind which is constantly set to false. after the Http calls are made and the ItemsSource has properties the items drop into the GridView. Am I also safe to assume I need to create `LoadingGridViewStyle`?

Comment: First, you should create a style, just copy the default style from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299128.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and replace the control template with the one in the answer. The progress bar will become visible when IsHitTestVisible turns to false, which means when IsLoaded is false, the progress bar should show up. Did you forget the converter?

Comment: Thanks for that, I copied over the default styles and replaced the ControlTemplate with yours but still no dice :( I updated the question to include the full <GridView> snippet with what you have suggested. Sorry to keep coming back, still reasonably inexperienced when it comes to XAML but I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, and I can see what's wrong in your code now. You have to define the style of your `GridView` *outside* itself. Place it inside the `Page.Resources` or even `App.Resources` since it's an implicit style (meaning you didn't give it a name so it will be applied to all `GridView`s).

Comment: I've now got the progress bar showing in multiple GridView's, but it doesn't look like `IsLoaded` is affecting `IsHitTestVisible`. IsLoaded it being set to false, and with `<GridView IsHitTestVisible="{ x:Bind IsLoaded }" ...` the progressbar doesn't disappear. When using `<GridView IsHitTestVisible="{ Binding IsLoaded }" ...` as you suggested, the XAML says it can't find the property IsLoaded due to an unknown DataContext. I'm doing `this.DataContext = this;` in my page constructor.

Comment: If you use xBind, remember the default mode is OneTime, so you need to specifically write Mode=OneWay in the end.

Comment: I was just about to write back! Either the IsHitTestVisible isn't changing or the ProgressBar isn't binding to the value properly. I've tried both x:bind and binding, all sorts of combinations.

Comment: Are you able to create a repo so I can test?

Comment: I will create a new project and repo with the identical code in for you, how should I let you know to give you access to the repo?

Comment: Can you post it on GitHub? VS has pretty good build-in support for it.

Comment: https://github.com/mbrewerton/MultiGridProgressBars I've got a repo up that's near enough identical to my project, and it's showing the same behaviour. Thank you for offering to take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149123/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-matt-brewerton).